# Point struct pointer to first block of dynamic allocated memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

In my code I have allocated some memory with my struct Song pointer called ptr
.
What I'm now trying to do is to create a second pointer that always point to the first struct in the allocated memory and use that to loop through all when I want to print the information.

It looks something like this in main:

```
#include "FuncDek.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>


int main() 
{
    //For swedish and check memory leak
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "swedish");

    //Create with starting size of 5
    Song *ptr = (Song *)malloc(sizeof(Song) * 5);
    Song *start = &(ptr[0]);

    int menuChoice = 0;
    int nrOfSongs = 0;
do
{
    system("cls");
    menuChoice = menu();

    switch (menuChoice)
    {
    case 1: 
        addSong(&ptr, &nrOfSongs);
        break;
    case 2:
        showList(&start, nrOfSongs, &ptr);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nFelaktigt val, försök igen\n");
        system("pause");
        break;
    }

} while (menuChoice != 0);

//TODO Free memory
//free(ptr);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

And I have to files that contains the function declarations/definitions which looks something like this:

```
#ifndef FUNCDEK
#define FUNCDEK

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char title[30];
    char artist[30];
    unsigned int year;

} Song;

int menu();
void addSong(Song *ptr, int *nrOfSongs);
void showList(Song *start, int nrOfSongs, Song *ptr);

#endif
```

And:

```
#include "FuncDek.h"
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

//Show menu and save the users choice
int menu()
{
    fflush(stdin);

    int choice = 0;

    printf("Menyval på låtlista\n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");
    printf("1. Lägg till låt \n");
    printf("2. Visa låtlista \n");
    printf("3. Blanda låtlistan \n");
    printf("4. Spara till fil \n");
    printf("0. Avsluta program \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    getchar();

    /*TODO FELHANTERING*/

    return choice;
}

//Add song to list
void addSong(Song *ptr, int *nrOfSongs)
{
    system("cls");
    Song temp;
    printf("Ange låtens namn:\n");
    int sizeOfTitle = sizeof(temp.title) / sizeof(temp.title[0]);
    fgets(temp.title, sizeOfTitle, stdin);
    printf("Ange artistens namn:\n");
    int sizeOfArt = sizeof(temp.artist) / sizeof(temp.artist[0]);
    fgets(temp.artist, sizeOfArt, stdin);
    printf("Ange året låtens släpptes: \n");
    scanf("%d", &temp.year);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfTitle; i++)
    {
        ptr->artist[i] = temp.artist[i];
        ptr->title[i] = temp.title[i];
    }

    ptr->year = temp.year;
    *ptr++;
    *nrOfSongs = *nrOfSongs + 1;

}

//Print all from list
void showList(Song *start, int nrOfSongs, Song *ptr)
{

    system("cls");
    printf("Song list\n");
    printf("-----------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        printf("Låt: %s \n", start->title);
        printf("Artist: %s \n", start->artist);
        printf("År: %d \n", start->year);
        start++;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

But when I run the showList function I get garbage values and I can also see that I don't read on the correct memory-location.
So my questions is how do I make my pointer called start to point to the first memory block in ptr?

Comment: The problem is not in the code posted.

Comment: Well, if first parameter has wrong value, then you need to fix it to have the right value, when calling the function... But you don't show that code, so we can't help... Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hyde forgot about that one. Just used it to see that ptr actually contained somethings which it does.
But my start pointer doesn't seem to be pointed to that

Comment: `Song *start = &(ptr[0]);` look fishy. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Lundin okay. Then I actually have no idea where the problem lies but can put in all the code if it's needed.

Comment: Single step through the code and watch the variable, to see where exactly it gets corrupted.

Comment: @anderssinho don't post all the code, but a [mcve] (yes this means some work for you)

Comment: Indeed, your code does not call `showList` anywhere, as far as I can see...

Comment: @MichaelWalz yeah I understand that. That's what I tried in the first example because I thought the problem lied there somewhere.

Comment: `addSong(&ptr, &nrOfSongs);` You are passing `Song **` for the first parameter but the function expects `Song *`. Your compiler should warn you of this.

Comment: @hyde correct, took to much away. Have edit it back to the code now

Comment: @JohnnyMopp hmm okay. I don't get the warnings there. Have to check that again

Answer (score -1):

You can consider using a C linked list.

[Here](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) is a good example.